# How do I add options to my Spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

So, I have a spinner set-up in my layout and I have implemented this code into the strings.xml:

```
 <string-array name="priority_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
</string-array>
```

I then put this code block into the onCreate():

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_info);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.priority_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But, for some reason my app crashes and the log cat points to this line of code saying NullPointerException:

```
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

spinner1 is not null, adapter is not null, and spinner is not null, so I don't know what could be the problem. Yet, the app works completely fine when I comment out this one line of code, so I know this line has to do with my app crashing.

Here's the xml code snippet so everyone knows that spinner1 exist:

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />
```

LogCat:

```
07-24 13:52:07.728: D/ActivityThread(24892): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
07-24 13:52:07.728: D/ActivityThread(24892): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
07-24 13:52:07.728: D/ActivityThread(24892): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
07-24 13:52:08.108: D/AbsListView(24892): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-24 13:52:08.659: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(24892): <ConfigWindowMatch:2136>: Format     RGBA_8888.
07-24 13:52:08.709: E/(24892): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
07-24 13:52:08.709: E/(24892): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
07-24 13:52:10.781: D/AbsListView(24892): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-24 13:52:10.921: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(24892): <ConfigWindowMatch:2136>: Format     RGBA_8888.
07-24 13:52:11.122: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24892): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans     cannot have a zero length
07-24 13:52:11.122: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24892): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-24 13:52:13.254: W/dalvikvm(24892): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught   exception (group=0x41bf4438)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.daymanager/com.example.daymanager.ActivityInfo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at com.example.daymanager.ActivityInfo.onCreate(ActivityInfo.java:31)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5160)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
07-24 13:52:13.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24892):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: did you load the layout in oncreate(). setContentView(R.layout.layout_with_spinner)?

Comment: What does the LogCat say?  Post the full error

Comment: @crocboy I have edited my question to show the logcat.

Comment: Which line in your `ActivityInfo` is line 31?

Comment: spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: That's the line causing your error.  So put some breakpoints in your app, and see which object is null

Comment: How do I do that, Ive never had to do that before?

Comment: or rather, how does breakpoints work when I'm running the code through my phone?

Comment: I'd love to explain it to you!  Do you have an email address I could contact you at?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your spinner is null. I think you forgot to load the layout. Call setContentView(R.layout.----) before findViewById

Comment: Ive updated the code snippet of my onCreate() to show you that I called setContentView(layout_with_spinner) before findViewById. Doesn't work.